# Build Jenkins Sonar-ruby-plugin

Tags: ruby, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to build sonar-ruby-plugin for jenkins i.e, to create a .hpi file every time I run the command:

```
mvn package
```

it creates a target folder but there is no .hpi file.

https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin

Answer (score 1):

This is a plugin for [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) server, not [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).

You should:

- build the plugin by `mvn package`
- copy to `SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins directory`
- restart [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)
- run analysis (you can execute [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) in Jenkins; read more on [SonarQube wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins))